# REST calls to different items of single lib return responses with different structures

Tags: rest, 2016, json

SP 2016 on-prem.
I have a test library with bunch of word documents. Calling to part of them return a response like:

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "716369bb-3f0e-48fb-845f-d4774d6198ac",
      "uri": "http://sptest/_api/Web/Lists(guid'0161e46c-50ab-4c7d-b098-ff16d3623784')/Items(7)",
      "etag": "\"1\"",
      "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"
    },
    "FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "http://sptest/_api/Web/Lists(guid'0161e46c-50ab-4c7d-b098-ff16d3623784')/Items(7)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"
      }
    },
    "RoleAssignments": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "http://sptest/_api/Web/Lists(guid'0161e46c-50ab-4c7d-b098-ff16d3623784')/Items(7)/RoleAssignments"
      }
    },
    "AttachmentFiles": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "ContentType": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "GetDlpPolicyTip": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "FieldValuesAsHtml": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "FieldValuesAsText": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "FieldValuesForEdit": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "http://sptest/_api/Web/Lists(guid'0161e46c-50ab-4c7d-b098-ff16d3623784')/Items(7)/FieldValuesForEdit"
      }
    },
    "File": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "Folder": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "ParentList": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": uri
      }
    },
    "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
    "Id": 7,
    "ContentTypeId": "0x0101003563CADD50FAD7458CC556B82DE76824",
    "Title": null,
    "SharedWithUsersId": null,
    "A": null,
    "ID": 7,
    "Created": "2018-01-19T11:27:17Z",
    "AuthorId": 1,
    "Modified": "2018-01-19T11:27:17Z",
    "EditorId": 1,
    "OData__CopySource": null,
    "CheckoutUserId": null,
    "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
    "GUID": "18de94b1-25d2-4bc6-9218-4c7ac04fcc58"
  }
}
```

The other returns no d-object just something like:

```
{
 "odata.metadata": "http://sptest/_api/$metadata#SP.ListData.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItems/@Element",
  "odata.type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem",
  "odata.id": "7948157f-bd75-4be3-a138-31b03df1ec86",
  "odata.etag": "\"2\"",
  "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'0161e46c-50ab-4c7d-b098-ff16d3623784')/Items(5)",
  "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
  "Id": 5,
  "ContentTypeId": "0x0101003563CADD50FAD7458CC556B82DE76824",
  "Title": null,
  "SharedWithUsersId": null,
  "A": false,
  "ID": 5,
  "Created": "2018-01-19T11:27:15Z",
  "AuthorId": 1,
  "Modified": "2018-02-25T10:08:48Z",
  "EditorId": 1,
  "OData__CopySource": null,
  "CheckoutUserId": null,
  "OData__UIVersionString": "2.0",
  "GUID": "fb980029-1420-41c1-8ab4-326dbd05828a"
}
```

And i have no idea why. What could cause this? I need to iterate over RoleAssignments of d of any selected item but somewhy this property is missing like the whole d-object.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are not sending the same `Accept` header in all GET requests.

You can set `Accept` header to:

- application/json (your second response)
- application/json;odata=nometadata
- application/json;odata=verbose (your first response)

Comment: I was just typing this.

Comment: Hi, Lukáš ! Well,  i'm sending the same  call for all of items - function do this for me.  Playing with  YARC!  gives the same result,  headers are always the same. BTW i've tried "odata=nometadata" with call to  item with ID=9,  still it returns d-object unlike item with ID=5. Mystery.

Comment: @Dadudki What is the difference between those two items? They are in the same library? Same document type? Permissions set the same? Checked Out status? What URL are you queriing?

Comment: No difference actually.  They are just bunch  of old docs in the test farm. Permission, checkout status - all the same. Only one of them has a version higher than 1.0.

Comment: Query  URL is very simple  - http://sptest/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(x),  only x is a variable.

Comment: Interesting detail. I have another (production) farm where i created  new  test SPWEB with Documents lib and copied (download and upload) there content  from test lib.   There are 11 Word files in both of them now.  I manually called with the same  URL pattern  all the files from both libs and found  that:   1.  Some calls to production lib also  response with no d-object 2. This is not the same files that response with no d-object  from test lib.   Now i'm puzzled even more.

Comment: I recommend to use different tool because YARC does not work as expected. I tried it and I had to refresh page when changing ``Accept`` header and sometimes it completely ignores my ``Accept`` header.

Comment: Lukáš, initially i've called items one by one from ajax- function with "odata=verbose" hardcoded. The problem is the same. Well, i've  reuploaded  documents  giving half-empty responses,  after that responses became normal.  Barely this is a solution. I could suspect my db,  but there is no such a problem to get RoleAssignmets via any other interface.    Still a mystery.